# How do I take screen shots on DVD movies and protected content?

Tags: macos, mac, screen-capture, mediaplayer

I saw this awesome movie that I watched on DVD and wanted to take a screen shot of it, but when I did, it was transparent. I could only see my desktop taken but not the movie. Is there a specific program or hack that could let me take a screen shot of that content? I tried every screen shot software, but still leaves it transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is deliberate from Apple and you will not be able to take screen shots using DVD player.

You can either use VLC and then a screen shot program (Cmd-3 and Cmd-4 works for me), or transcode your DVD to a QuickTime movie using Handbrake (which may take too long for you to find it interesting).  The latter will allow you to use QuickTime player which can do quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to control & click 'use current frame as jacket picture'. Then click stop, your selected frame should come up - no matter where you stop the film from now on this still is what will show, that's what 'jacket picture' means.

Take a screenshot of the Jacket Picture & it should come up on your desktop like normal!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, user62394! The suggestion of using the Jacket picture is definitely the best option, in my opinion. I tried VLC, but even with a brand new iMac and 8gb RAM and nothing else open VLC really didn't playback my dvd well at all. Granted, I tried to follow some suggestions from the read me file to fix the playback, but I don't know enough about video filetypes, etc to really deal with that program. I am so glad there is a workaround within the mac software, its just easier

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to capture screen shots by playing the movie in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) and pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18249/take-snapshots-of-your-favorite-movie-scenes-in-vlc/) is a more detailed guide for the windows version of VLC, but it should apply for the mac version as well!